# How can Postgres clusters be managed on a Windows EnterpriseDB of Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, enterprisedb

To clarify, I am using plain Postgres as packaged by EnterpriseDB (with StackBuilder), *not* EDB Postgres Advanced Server.

I'm familiar with using `pg_lsclusters`, `pg_dropcluster`, and `pg_createcluster` on Linux. These tools don't seem to be installed by the Windows x86-64 EnterpriseDB installer (not recognized at the command line), and I don't see any graphical tools that are added to the Start Menu by the installer (which includes the StackBuilder, a Reload Configuration shortcut, and a psql Console).

Comment: `pg_lscluster` is not a native Postgres tool and it's not a general "Linux" tool either. It's only available on Ubuntu, not on other distributions. What exactly are you trying to do? If you need a new cluster, you need to run `initdb` and then register a corresponding Windows service for that cluster.

Comment: OK. Are there Windows equivalents for listing clusters or dropping clusters? You're right, I'm most familiar with this from Ubuntu, but need to install it on Windows right now (not for production).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - can't they just run on separate ports?

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW: sure they can, but to create a new cluster you will have to run `initdb` (and provide a different port when running it)